# In App Purchase Failed “Cannot connect to iTunes Store” error

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I am facing this issue since last two months

My App is live with auto-renew InApp purchase before it was working fine then many user complained that when they click on Buy Button Nothing happens so i debug my code and run on my real device I found this error

failed SKPrdouctName
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

i did not change any code

i did not upload new build

My product is also Approved on Appstore Connect

I did not change anything on the product

I already tried Restarting device, clear caches, login logout apple id still getting the same error

This is happening to many live users

I really need a solution to this

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print(response.products)
    products = response.products
    for product in response.products {
        print(product.localizedTitle)
    }
}

func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
    print(request)
    Global.sharedInstance.isConsiderPurchasedOrNot = true
}
```

}

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
       for transaction in transactions {
        print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing:
            
           
            break
        case .purchased:
             Miscellaneous.APPDELEGATE.window!.stopMyToastActivity()
            if Global.sharedInstance.isConsiderPurchasedOrNot{
                print(transaction.payment.productIdentifier + "is purchased")
                
                let prodID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier as String
                
                if prodID == MyProducts.autoRenewSubscription
                {
                    Global.sharedInstance.isPurchased = 1
                  
                    purchaseSubscriber(usediD: Global.getUserID())
                }
            }
         break
        case .restored:
            print(transaction.payment.productIdentifier + "is purchased/restored! hello ")
    
              //  let str1 =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username")
                Global.sharedInstance.isPurchased = 1
            let prodID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier as String
            Miscellaneous.APPDELEGATE.window!.stopMyToastActivity()
            if prodID == MyProducts.autoRenewSubscription
            {
                Global.sharedInstance.isPurchased = 1
                
            }


        case .failed:
            print(transaction.payment.productIdentifier + "is failed!")
             Miscellaneous.APPDELEGATE.window!.stopMyToastActivity()

           
        default: queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share some of code snippets?

Comment: i have updated in question Can you check ?